# Enum with string index or alternative

Tags: vb.net, enums

Is it possible to return a value from `enum` with a `string` index? For example I can use:

```
Enum test
    firstval
    secondval
    thirdval
End Enum

Dim index As Integer = 1

CType(index, test).ToString()
```

to return `firstval` but is there a way to do something similar where index is a `string` value? For example:

```
Enum test
    firstval = "one"
    secondval = "two"
    thirdval = "three"
End Enum

Dim index As string = "one"

CType(index, test).ToString()
```

Comment: First of all, you can't set `Enum` as `string`: *The Enum statement can declare the data type of an enumeration. Each member takes the enumeration's data type. You can specify Byte, Integer, Long, SByte, Short, UInteger, ULong, or UShort.*

Comment: Use `Dictionary<string,string>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible using an `Enum`, but you could easily create a type that can do what you want, using the `Narrowing` operator.

simple example:

```
Class Test

    Private Shared _lookup As Dictionary(Of String, Test)

    Private Key As String
    Private Name As String

    Public Shared ReadOnly firstval  As Test = New Test("one", "firstval")
    Public Shared ReadOnly secondval As Test = New Test("two", "secondval")
    Public Shared ReadOnly thirdval  As Test = New Test("three", "thirdval")

    Private Sub New(key As String, name As String)
        Me.Key = key
        Me.Name = name
        If _lookup Is Nothing Then _
            _lookup = New Dictionary(Of String, Test)

        _lookup.Add(key, Me)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Name ' or whatever you want '
    End Function

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(obj As Test) As String 
        Return obj.Key
    End Operator 

    Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(key As String) As Test
        Return _lookup(key)
    End Operator 

End Class
```

usage:

```
Dim index As string = "one"

' returns firstval '
CType(index, Test).ToString()
```

Comment: Wow that looks great! I'm not sure I understand exactly what is going on with the widening and narrowing operators, do you know of any references for that? I tried googling but I didn't come up with much!

Comment: @doovers [How to: Define a Conversion Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7b9sy7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are several other alternatives.

One is to get the names used in the enum.  For instance:

```
Friend Enum ImgFormat
    Bitmap
    GIF
    JPeg
    TIFF
    PNG
End Enum

Dim ImgNames() As String
...
ImgNames = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(ImgFormat))
```

If your names are not friendly enough, decorate them with Descriptions:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Friend Enum ImgFormat
    <Description("Bitmap (BMP)")> Bitmap
    <Description("Graphic Interchange (GIF)")> GIF
    <Description("Jpg/JPeg (JPG)")> JPeg
    <Description("Tagged Image (TIFF)")> TIFF
    <Description("Portable Graphics (PNG)")> PNG
End Enum
```

To get the descriptions, requires reflection which gets involved:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class EnumConverter
' gets a single enum description
Public Shared Function GetEnumDescription(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
    Dim fi As FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
    Dim attr() As DescriptionAttribute = _
        DirectCast( _
            fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), _
            DescriptionAttribute() )

       If attr.Length > 0 Then
           Return attr(0).Description
       Else
           Return EnumConstant.ToString()
       End If
End Function

' get all the enum descriptions:
Public Shared Function GetEnumDescriptions(ByVal type As Type) As String()
    Dim n As Integer = 0

    Dim enumValues As Array = [Enum].GetValues(type)
    Dim Descr(enumValues.Length - 1) As String

    For Each value As [Enum] In enumValues
         Descr(n) = GetEnumDescription(value)
         n += 1
    Next

    Return Descr

End Function
End Class
```

To use:

```
Dim ImgNames() As String = EnumConverter.GetEnumDescriptions(ImgFormat)
```

`ImgNames(ImgFormat.GIF)` would be 'Graphic Interchange (GIF)'

This will break if the Enum values are not the default 0, 1, 2 ...  IF that is an issue (and it really is), then build a class around it to store the Name or Description with the Enum Value.  Rather than building a class to create a pseudo enum, make one to create a list of name-value pairs consisting of the Descriptions and Enum Value.

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about getting the description using the enum value?

Comment: Use the `EnumConverter` class (shown) to get the Description to an array, then a given Enum value (when default vals 0123...) is also an index into the array for that description (as shown).  If `x` is `ImgFormat.GIF` then `ImgNames(x)` would be 'Graphic Interchange (GIF)'